# how to solve homogenous differential equation $(x+y)^2 \space dx = xy \space dy$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

i am stuck in this , first i find value of
$$dy/dx = (x+y)^2 / xy \tag{i}$$
let $y = vx$

differentiating both sides :
$$dy/dx = v + x \space dv/dx \tag{ii}$$

I tried to solve using equation $(i)$  and $(ii)$ but I am stuck.

$(x+y)^2 \space dx = xy \space dy$

Comment: After the transformation, your ODE becomes \begin{align} xv' + v &= (1+v)^{2}/v \\ \implies xvv' + v^{2} &= 1 + 2v + v^{2} \\ \implies xvv' &= 1 + 2v \\ \implies \frac{v dv}{1+2v} &= \frac{1}{x} dx \end{align} which can be integrated using integration by parts.

Answer (score 1):

I'm skipping some initial steps as you've figured that out. As $y=vx\implies \frac{y}{x}=v$.

The original equation finally reduces to
$$v+x\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{1}{v}+v+2\\ \implies x\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{1+2v}{v}\\ \implies \frac{vdv}{1+2v}=\frac{dx}{x}$$

Can you take it up from here?

Comment: my mistake that i should have mention till what i finished,  i was stucked in the same line as  you have shown , but i have solved using 1/2 ∫(2v + 1 - 1)dv/1 + 2v

Answer (score 1):

We are given that $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{(x+y)^2}{xy}$, substituting $y=vx$ in the rhs, we notice that $\frac{(x+y)^2}{xy}=\frac{1}{v}+v+2$, and from $y=vx$, by differentiating both sides with respect to $x$ we get, $\frac{dy}{dx}=v+x \frac{dv}{dx}$. Replacing the value of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and $\frac{(x+y)^2}{xy}$, in the original equation we get,
$$v+x \frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{1}{v}+v+2$$
$$\implies x \frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{1}{v}+2$$
$$\implies x \frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{1+2v}{v}$$
$$\implies \frac{vdv}{1+2v}=\frac{dx}{x}$$
$$\implies \int\frac{vdv}{1+2v}=\int\frac{dx}{x}$$
The LHS integral is a simple U-substitution and the RHS is $\log_ex$